# R Shiny: Click and jump to different tab passing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny

Is there any way to click an element in a dataTableOutput and then jump to a different tabPanel?

I know using **escape = FALSE** could add url to the table element. But how to add "jumping to a different tab" to a dataTableOutput element? And passing values?

Please take a look at my reproducible example. Thanks.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  X = data.frame(
    ID = c(
      "<a href = 'http://www.google.com'> google </a>",
      "Click here then Jump to tab2 and pass x=2 and y=2 to tab2",
      "Click here then Jump to tab2 and pass x=3 and y=4 to tab2"
    ),
    x = c(1, 2, 3),
    y = c(10, 2, 4)
  )
  output$datatable = renderDataTable({X}, escape = FALSE,
  options = list(
    paging = FALSE,
    searching = FALSE,
    filtering = FALSE,
    ordering = FALSE
  ))
  output$text = renderText(paste("X = ", "Y = "))
}

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("tab1", dataTableOutput("datatable")),
  tabPanel("tab2", textOutput("text"))
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Luckily, there is no need for JS, or jQuery, since all those things can be done on Shinyserver side.

Okay, where do we start... DT has an inbuild callback feature to acess which rows/columns/cells were clicked by the user. See example [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-selection/). Then there is no reason to "send" this information to `tab2`, but we can just do with this information what we wanted to. Like setting the text in `tab2` appropriately. In order to change tabs, shiny has the `updateTabsetPanel` function that lets you change tabs without any hyperlinks.

Kind of a changelog:

- insertet the `observeEvent` for functionality.
- added `selected` and `server` attribute to get a single row callback
- added Id to `tabsetPanel` to enable communication.
- got rid of the google link and `escape`.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  X = data.frame(
    ID = c("Click here then Jump to tab2 and pass x=1 and y=10 to tab2", 
           "Click here then Jump to tab2 and pass x=2 and y=2 to tab2",
           "Click here then Jump to tab2 and pass x=3 and y=4 to tab2"),
    x = c(1,2,3),
    y = c(10,2,4)    
  )

  output$datatable = renderDataTable({X}, selection = "single", server = FALSE,
                                     options = list(paging=FALSE,
                                                    searching=FALSE,
                                                    filtering=FALSE,
                                                    ordering=FALSE)
                                     )
  observeEvent(input$datatable_rows_selected, {
    row <- input$datatable_rows_selected 
    output$text <- renderText({paste("X =", X[row, "x"], "Y =", X[row, "y"])})
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "mainPanel", selected = "tab2")
  })  
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  tabsetPanel(id = "mainPanel", 
    tabPanel("tab1",dataTableOutput("datatable")),
    tabPanel("tab2",textOutput("text"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```